# .htaccess : load from folder based on TLD

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to make functionality described as follows:

example.com will load content from webhosting_root/com/ but URI stays example.com
example.es from webhosting_root/es/ , URI: example.es
example.pl from webhosting_root/pl/ , URI: example.pl
example.cz from webhosting_root/cz/ , URI: example.cz
...

All domains are set to route to one webhosting.

I think this is achievable by .htaccess rules? But i am not sure how to do this. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:

`.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/com/
RewriteRule (.*) /com/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.es$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/es/
RewriteRule (.*) /es/$1 [L]

...
```